# How would I filter a list with linq to produce the following result

Tags: c#, linq

Would like to be able to filter the first list to only include RepID 26 Amts otherwise Amt = 0 rep = null

```
Id Number       Amt       RepID
23J011-001  $65,000     26
23J011-001  $38,000     28
23J011-001  $47,500     32
23J011-001  $40,000     45
23J011-001  $80,000     48
23J011-002  $95,000     26
23J011-002  $70,000     28
23J011-002  $95,000     32
23J011-002  $100,000    45
23J011-002  $75,000     48
23J011-003      
23J011-004  $50,000     29
        
Id Number   Amt       RepID
23J011-001  $65,000     26
23J011-002  $95,000     26
23J011-003      
23J011-004
```

Have tried various DistinctBy and GroupBy but not able to come up with a solution
One try
aList.Where(x => x.RepID == 26).DistinctBy(x => x.IdNumber).ToList();

Comment: Sounds like you want an outer join: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: It seems all you need is a simple where clause with these conditions 
`aList.Where(x => x.RepID == 26 || x.RepID == null && x.Amt == 0)`

Comment: Why does your answer table show `23J011-004` as being included?

Comment: @CarloBos I would always suggest using parentheses when chaining logical operators...

Comment: @NetMage operator precedence has && before || so this is correct.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=msvc-170

Comment: @CarloBos Yes, I know, I just think it is bad practice to not use parens.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary operators:

aList.Where(x => x.RepID == 26? true : (x.RepID == null && x.Amt == 0)).ToList()